# Could not connect to MongoDB on the provided host and port

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

I just want to try MongoDB Compass GUI for MongoDB, but when I try to connect using local host port: 27017 I get this error:

> Could not connect to MongoDB on the provided host and port

I followed [these](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XfLeO_LE6ic) instructions on YouTube.

Answer (score 53):

I had faced this issue today and later I found that it was a set up problem. If you are also facing this issue while you set up MongoDB for the first time, following steps may help you. Make sure that `MongoDB` service has been started in `services.msc`.

1. Go to C drive and create a folder `db` in the path `C:\data\db`, if you don't see `data` folder in C drive, please create it first and then `db` folder as @sebastian mentioned in the comment.
2. Go the folder, where you had installed MongoDB, in my case, it was `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin`
3. Type the command `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin>mongod`
4. This will set up the MongoDB on your machine, and you will get an output as preceding.

> C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin>mongod
>   2018-03-11T07:02:56.558-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB
>   starting : pid=18720 port=27017 dbpath=C:\data\db\ 64-bit
>   host=SibeeshVenu 2018-03-11T07:02:56.558-0700 I CONTROL 
>   [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2

5. Now if you try connecting, you may not be getting the issue.

[image]

Comment: this works, I was also facing the issue and I installed first time.

Comment: can I create the `db` folder in the path other than `C:\data\db`?

Comment: this answer worked out for my problem but there are different things may cause this, so I'm not accepting this answer to not mislead people

Comment: @EgeKuzubasioglu I do agree, but leaving a question unaccepted will result in, this question be available in unanswered/unaccepted category.

Comment: Thanks, Sibeesh Venu All I did is created C:\data\db path and run mongod using cmd, after mongo with another cmd and it worked :)

Comment: thanks i did all of this but i had to create the C:\data folder and then the db folder and just simply typed mongod into the command line

Comment: @Sebastian Thanks, I will add this to the answer.

Answer (score 35):

Press windows key button and search **Services** and find *MongoDB* then start. Then try again. It will work

Comment: Thanks a lot, this did the trick for me ... i knew it was a mater of a simple restart, cause every thing worked fine before and i didn't made any change on my config

Comment: Super. Why did this came to my mind earlier... Thanks a lot

Comment: Worked well --- It's strange that this works, but dosen't work when restarting from cmd promt...

Answer (score 19):

In case other people have this error, here is what worked for me:

- Edit /etc/mongod.conf
- Under network comment out the following by placing a # at the beginning of the line:

  bindIp: 127.0.0.1

-- What went wrong: --

Reason: bindIp was causing it to reject external requests, so we need to remove that setting.

My mongo was the standard yum install for Red Hat (RHEL6) and this is how it was configured by default (I had started with mongoDB 2.6 and upgraded in steps to 3.4).

**EDIT**: For MongoDB 2.4 and earlier use:
bind_ip = 127.0.0.1

Comment: Could you please share steps for windows server?

Comment: this is the correct answer.  the spelling is bind_ip = 127.0.0.1 in my server though.

Comment: Or you can use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost for connection.

Answer (score 14):

Struggled for 3 hours.
Here is full procedure in 3 steps:

---

## *On MongoDB server machine*

Get the IP adresss:

1. run `CMD` or Command prompt
2. run `ipconfig` command
   Look for a line that is like below
       IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : `10.111.11.111`
3. Copy above IP value, which is 10.111.11.111, it can be different for you

Edit the bindIP in MongoDB Server config file:

1. Open  `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin\mongod.cfg`
   Look for the below line:
   `bindIp: 127.0.0.1`
2. Add a COMMA at the end, and paste the copied IP, like below:
   `bindIp: 127.0.0.1,10.111.11.111`

**NOTE**: If your IP address changes everyday, then best is to write the computer name (type `hostname` in `cmd` to get the name of your computer)

Restart the MongoDB Server

1. run the `services.msc` command
   scroll down on the right to select `MongoDB Server`
   on the left-top, `Restart the service`

---

## *On Client machine*

Connect to MongoDb server, from another machine

Now, you can connect from another machine.
Use a client, like `MongoDB Compass` or other:

1. Connection is possible using it's IP `10.111.11.111`, give it in `Hostname` in MongoDB Compass client
2. `Hostname` in MongoDB Compass client can also be the server's computer name like W11ABC11A11. To get computer name of your MongoDB server, use `hostname` in `CMD`(on the MongoDB server computer).

---

## Troubleshooting/ issues?

After doing all above, if you have issues, then:
- ping each other (client from server, and vice versa) using `ipconfig`, using command `ping IPhere` , you should get `Reply from ..` should not get `Request timed out.`
- if you see issues in above:
-- Restart the client machine, ping again
-- If you still have issues, have DB owner to restart the server machine once (if it is dev server there should not be any problem to restart when its idle.)
-- issues still? verify all above steps

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me. Thank you!

Comment: For me, comma separating with 0.0.0.0 worked (instead of entirely replacing the existing IP). So I have bindIp: 127.0.0.1,0.0.0.0. Hoping this means I don't need to change the IP if the host IP is dynamic.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem

1. try to enable cmd enter the command  ->  **mongod**
2. then try to connect using the MongoDb Compass program
   You must have an open console all the time

Answer (score 5):

edit `/etc/mongod.conf`

Under the net settings

```
bindIp: 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: Change the bindIp works for me. I also disable the firewalld service.

Answer (score 4):

It's a common problem if you are working on **Windows**.

Open your task manager and go to the Services tab. Check if the MongoDB server is stopped or not. If stopped, right click on it and start the server. 
Then try again. The problem will be solved.

Comment: OP didn't specify that they were working in a Windows environment. Not all operating systems have a Task Manager.

Answer (score 1):

Wasted a lot of time on this, seemingly tried it all and literally none of these solutions worked for me...

Ultimately, my MongoDb seems to want to ignore my config file, since commenting out the bind_ip field should do the same thing.

Try starting mongo like this

```
mongod --bind_ip_all
```

Alternatively, you can specify specific IPs

```
mongod --bind_ip <IP>
```

Answer (score 0):

- please start mongoDB before use Compass GUI

Answer (score 0):

My **MongoDB** Installed machine firewall was enabled that's why I can not from Remote machine **MongoDB** compass

After disabled the firewall, I am able to connect from **Remote MongoDB** compass.

```
[17:32:51 oracle@test2 bin]$ service firewalld stop
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check if 27017 port is enabled / Opened in your .conf file .. This is because 27017 port is not opened as default and also you need to add your IP in the TCP IN to make your internet IP connect remotely..

Answer (score 0):

It's a common problem if you are working on Windows.

Creating `data/db` folder on `c` drive and then running mongod from `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin`
and then connecting from mongodb compass resolves my issue

basicly on c drive you should have `data` folder which holds `db` folder that's what i understood by this 
i just shared someone might get help from this :)

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar problem while using MongoDB on EC2 instance and was trying to connect to it through Mongodb compass.

On Mongodb Compass authentication screen, changing the port to 443 worked because my mongod service was listening on 443.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am on Ubuntu and I simply did it by checking the 'mongod.conf' file.
Make sure that following parameters are set:

> ```
> net:
>   port: 27017
>   bindIp: 127.0.0.1
> ```

And after every change I suggest you go with

> sudo systemctl restart mongod.service

Answer (score 0):

By default IPv6 disabled and this may be a reason of the failed connection by Hostname.
Try to add IPv6 support:

```
# network interfaces
net:
  ipv6: true
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1, MyDomain.com
```